# Supress recv() function in python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, recv

Is there any way to supress `recv()` function in python socket programming??

Suppose server sent a `recv()` to client

before getting data from client server sent another `recv()` to client

Then the first `recv()` should be ignored.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Comment: lol, if you have screwed up your app-level protocol ,don't blame syscalls for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your application to decide what to ignore.

If you need that functionality, you have to provide *information* (e.g.: timestamps) in the packets and you have to *delay* their processing enough so you can recieve the newer packets.

Answer (score 0):

recv() and send() are used for sending and receiving data. Once you have received data using recv(), it's upto whether you want to do something with it or you can just ignore it.